# jquery click event on element not having a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I make sure that this href element is will fire "click" event unless it does NOT have "disablelink" class.

DO NOT PROCESS:

```
<a class="iconGear download disablelink" href="#">Download</a>
```

PROCESS:

```
<a class="iconGear download" href="#">Download</a>
```

---

tried this without success:

```
    $("a.download").not(".disablelink").click(function (e) {
        alert('in');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("a.download:not('.disablelink')").click(function (e) {
    alert('in');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If the `disablelink` class is being added dynamically:

```
$(document).on('click', "a.download:not('.disablelink')", function (e) {
    alert('in');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Check this **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/d3rXr/1/

Comment: this will not work if he adds the disablelink class dynamically.

Comment: ..plus its the exact same statement OP already uses, just slower.

Comment: @Rodik - Added a variant that should work even if class is dynamically added.

Comment: @jAndy - same: yes to an extend (even though this is a sinlge selector version). But slower? is `:not` slower than `.not()`?

Comment: @techfoobar: in most cases using inlined-selector statements like `:not` is slower than their *functional* variants. Just because it will invoke *Sizzle* to reduce/filter the resultset whereas the function will just `.slice()`/`.filter()` the list. See http://jsperf.com/sizzle-not-vs-functional-not

Comment: @jAndy - Tks for that info. I was under the apparently wrong impression the result set to begin with itself will be the reduced one when using inlined-selectors. Didn't think there would be additional slicing/filtering involved.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.download').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass('disablelink')){
        return;
    }else{
      //other stuff;
    }
});
```

Why don't you check when the anchor is clicked, and if it has the class it returns and does nothing, which would be more readable code I guess.

Comment: what's the big deal about if else ?

Comment: you are asking to do something **if** some expression is true... only without the **if** statement...

Comment: What ? I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You could go like this:

```
$("a.download").click(function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass("disablelink")) {
        return false;
    }
    // Normal code
    alert('in');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this probably doesn't work because some links had disablelink added to them dynamically, and after they already had the click handler bound to them.

Secondly, you should just check for that class inside the click handler, like so:

```
$("a.download").click(function (e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('disablelink')){
       e.preventDefault();
       // link is disabled
    }else{
       alert('in');
       // link is active
    } 
});
```